# Why is overflow-y required for a CSS parallax effect?

Tags: css, overflow, parallax

I have created a barebones parallax demo. This works fine, as you can see if you run the snippet below. However, it stops working if I remove the following CSS rule:

```
main {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Why is it necessary to include a rule for a vertical scrollbar, when there is no need to scroll vertically?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  main {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    perspective: 2px;

    /* overflow-y MUST be set to a certain value for parallax to work
      * WORKS:
      * + auto
      * + hidden
      * + overlay
      * + scroll
      * FAILS:
      * - clip
      * - inherit
      * - initial
      * - revert
      * - unset
      * - visible
    */
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 100%;
  }

  div:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
    background-color: #900;
  }

  div:nth-child(2) {
    left: 49.5vw;
    background: rgba(0,192,0,0.5);
    height: 80%;
    top: 10%;

    transform: translateZ(1px) scale(0.5);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  div:nth-child(3) {
    left: 99vw;
    background-color: #009;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
       <div></div
      ><div></div
      ><div></div>
    </main>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it necessary to include a rule for a vertical scrollbar, when there is no need to scroll vertically?

You need to scroll vertically but you need to scroll the `main` and no the sceen. There is a small trap here because removing the scroll of the `main` will make the default scroll of the screen to appear and you think both are the same but no. We need to scroll the main because the perspective is defined there.

Reduce the width/height slightly and you will better understand. now if you remove/add overflow you will see that it's different

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  perspective: 2px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 99vw;
  height: 100%;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #900;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 49.5vw;
  background: rgba(0, 192, 0, 0.5);
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translateZ(1px) scale(0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  left: 99vw;
  background-color: #009;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Basically, the element having the perspective need to have its content scrolling to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks Temani Alif! By default, an element is set to `overflow: visible;`, but setting overflow for one axis to a different value sets overflow for the *other* axis to `auto` by default, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#description). That is the detail that I had not understood.

Comment: If I use the screen as the main scrolling to avoid needing overflow (which messes with fixed elements), parallax stops working, even though I am scrolling through the page. Why does it need a child element with scrolling enabled, instead of just a scrolling page?